# UIStoryboard change UITabBar Text programmatically

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I am writing program with `UIStoryboard` (named as MainStoryboard) and use `UITabBarController`. In my app setting, I choose *MainStoryboard* as Main interface.

In my **AppDelegate**,

1) How can I access to my *MainStoryboard*? (Currently, I don't need to set that storyboard as my root view controller. I already choose *MainStoryboard* as main interface. Now, I need to access *MainStoryboard*)

2) How can I change tab bar button text?

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the UIStoryboard class reference for a suitable method?

Comment: no. I haven't. Can you pls guide me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change tab bar items only after you have instantiated the view controller. So in your *AppDelegate* do the following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UITabBarController *tbc = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    NSArray<UIViewController *> *vca = tbc.viewControllers;

    [vca enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIViewController * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        UITabBarItem *tbi = obj.tabBarItem;
        tbi.title = @"MY_NEW_TITLE";
    }];

    // By the way your storyboard is here:
    UIStoryboard *sb = tbc.storyboard;

    return YES;
}
```